# Remote debugging of Azure cloud service from different machines

Tags: azure, remote-debugging

We have the following scenario:
We have three developer machines (Dev A, Dev B, Dev C) with VS 2013 Ultimate and Azure SDK 2.3 and all in the same network behind the same firewall.

When Dev A deploys a Cloud Service (with Debug as Build Config and Remote Debugging enabled for all roles), Dev A is able to attach the remote debugger. Dev B and Dev C get this message box.

[image]

When Dev B redeployes the exact same code, Dev B can attach the remote debugger, Dev A is no more able to do so. Dev C is still not able to do so.

So: is there a possibility (with certificate?) that any of the Dev can deploy the cloud service and the two other Devs are able to attach the remote debugger without to redeploy anew.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use remote debugger from different machines using following steps.

1) Open certmgr.msc on the machine from which you deployed your cloud service (let's say Dev A). Navigate to Personal -> Certificates in certmgr.msc. Under there you'll see a certificate issued by "Windows Azure Tools" with friendly name "RemoteDebugger". Export the certificate

2) On the different machine (Dev B, Dev C), import the certificate exported at step 1.

Now, you should be able to use remote debugger from all Dev A, Dev B and Dev C machines.

Make sure that you share your certificate whenever you do a new deployment. A new certificate is generated whenever you deploy cloud service with remote debugger enabled. You'll need the latest certificate to use remote debugger.